# POST - метод передает значение параметра(строку) не полностью

Tags: html, post, jsp

Хочу передать POST - методом строку, к примеру, "Ларионова Надежда Николаевна", следующим путем:

```
<select name="lawyer">
    <option value="Ларионова Надежда Николаевна">Ларионова Надежда Николаевна</option>");
</select>
```

В сервлете получаю "Ларионова" вместо целой строки, если это как - то поможет, то на всякий случай:  использую портлеты в jsp - страницах.

```
out.println("<select name=\"lawyer\">");
    out.println("<option selected value=" + lawyerNames.get(0) + ">" + lawyerNames.get(0) + "</option>");
    for(String lawyerName : lawyerNames) {
        out.println("<option value=" + lawyerName + ">" + lawyerName + "</option>");
    }
    out.println("</select>");
```

Почему получаю не целую строку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по этой строке

```
out.println("<option value=" + lawyerName + ">" + lawyerName + "</option>");
```

На выходе у вас получается

```
<option value=Ларионова Надежда Николаевна>Ларионова Надежда Николаевна</option>
```

Значение `value` не заключено в кавычки, поэтому учитывается только набор символов до пробела

Comment: Спасибо, действительно забыл заключить строку в кавычки!